# PHP check empty string

Tags: php, string

How can we check string is empty or not in PHP my string output is like this when i use `var_dump($string)`

> string(101) ""

I have tried 
`if(empty($string))` 
also have tried 
`if($string == '')` 
i also tried 
`trim($string)` 
to remove spaces but still its not working always going on **else** not on **if** condition.
When i use `htmlspecialchars($string)` its returning me a commented html in it how can i ignore this html or make this string empty if i get commented HTML in it.

Comment: try var_dump($string)

Comment: the output is from var_dump

Comment: let see what's inside $string: `echo urlencode($string)`

Comment: `if (strlen($string) === 0){};`

Comment: @Federkun when i use htmlspecialchars($string) its returning me commented html that's why i guess its not empty

Comment: it's not empty, there are 101 byte inside it, we know that. **what's the output of `echo urlencode($string)`?**

Answer (score 1):

If `empty` doesn't work for you, you have a problem with obtaining your string. Both `empty` and `strlen` will not give you the desired result (since your string is 101 characters long as `var_dump` suggests).

[`strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) is used to get the number of characters in a string; while [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) is used to test if a variable is actually empty:

```
empty(""); //will return true
strlen(""); // will return 0
```

I benchmarked both possibilities:

```
for($i=0; $i<1000000000; $i++)
{
    strlen("");
}
// This process used 333595 ms for its computations
// It spent 30 ms in system calls

for($i=0; $i<1000000000; $i++)
{
    empty("");
}
// This process used 73732 ms for its computations
// It spent 14 ms in system calls
```

So `empty` is faster.

Comment: the issue was in my string it was not empty but showing me empty on var_dump

Comment: So the problem is somewhere else, hence the question is not a valid one

Answer (score 0):

The commentary is right you can check if the string is empty when you check how long the string is.

The function in PHP is if strlen($string).
It's give you back 0 or the length so you can catch the 0

```
if (strlen($string) === 0){};
```